# Why is that np.nan is not boolean True

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

As we know that like zero value is boolean False, my question is that why `bool(np.nan)` is `True`. Python version is 3.7

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> bool(np.nan)
True
```

Comment: I think you should edit your code snipped. You asked why np.nan is True, but the snippet shows that it is False

Comment: it is merely *convention* that the truth value of numeric types is *anything but 0 is True, and 0 is false*. `nan` is not `0`

Comment: @soon, I fix the fault. Sorry, I have no privilege to upload the picture.

Comment: But, when we deal with the value nan, it looks  like zero-behavior so much, maybe more like None. So can you give some more detailed information?thx @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @RayZen, numbers are not booleans and it is fine to perform additional checks while converting them to booleans. If you are dealing with them like `bool(val)` then you are most likely doing something wrong - at least from the business logic. Writing `val != 0` is more natural. And you can check for nan using `isnan` methods (numpy provides it, as well as standard library)

Comment: @RayZen it may be like zero. One is also like zero in many ways, it is the multiplicative identity, for example, but one is not zero. NaN has properties different from zero as well, although some similar. But again, that is besides the point. It may or may not be similar to zero, but it is *not equal to zero*. Indeed, one unique fact about `nan` is that *it is not equal to anything, not even itself*;

Comment: ok, I got the point. Thanks for your tips